# Ubuntu does not recognize my smart card reader

Tags: ubuntu, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I am using Ubuntu 18 and trying to write code to use a smart card.
I am using ACS APG8201-b2 smart card reader, and I have installed [the official driver](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/456/apg8201-b2-smart-card-reader-with-pinpad/) (PC/SC Driver Package  3.04 MB, Version 1.1.8, 10-Jan-2020), and `libpcsclite-dev`.
As a starting point, I am trying to run Ludovic Rousseau's sample C code [here](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-c.html).
I can compile my code `ApduTool.c` as:

```c
    #ifdef WIN32
    #undef UNICODE
    #endif
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <winscard.h>
    
    #ifdef WIN32
    static char *pcsc_stringify_error(LONG rv)
    {
     static char out[20];
     sprintf_s(out, sizeof(out), "0x%08X", rv);
    
     return out;
    }
    #endif
    
    #define CHECK(f, rv) \
        if (SCARD_S_SUCCESS != rv) \
        { \
            printf(f ": %s\n", pcsc_stringify_error(rv)); \
            return -1; \
        }
    
    int main(void)
    {
        LONG rv;
    
        SCARDCONTEXT hContext;
        LPTSTR mszReaders;
        SCARDHANDLE hCard;
        DWORD dwReaders, dwActiveProtocol, dwRecvLength;
    
        SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendPci;
        BYTE pbRecvBuffer[258];
        BYTE cmd1[] = { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0A, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x06, 0x01 };
        BYTE cmd2[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    
        unsigned int i;
    
        rv = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL, &hContext);
        CHECK("SCardEstablishContext", rv)
    
        #ifdef SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE
            dwReaders = SCARD_AUTOALLOCATE;
            rv = SCardListReaders(hContext, NULL, (LPTSTR)&mszReaders, &dwReaders);
            CHECK("SCardListReaders", rv)
        #else
            rv = SCardListReaders(hContext, NULL, NULL, &dwReaders);
            CHECK("SCardListReaders", rv)
            mszReaders = calloc(dwReaders, sizeof(char));
            rv = SCardListReaders(hContext, NULL, mszReaders, &dwReaders);
            CHECK("SCardListReaders", rv)
        #endif
    
        printf("reader name: %s\n", mszReaders);
        return 0;
    }
```

using `Makefile`:

```
all: ApduTool.c
    gcc -c ApduTool.c -lsqlite3 -lpcsclite -lcrypto -lssl -I/usr/local/include/PCSC/ -I/usr/lib/ -I.
    gcc ApduTool.o -o ApduTool -lsqlite3 -lpcsclite -lcrypto -lssl -I/usr/local/include/PCSC/ -I/usr/lib/ -I.
clean:
    rm -f ApduTool *.o
```

When I run ApduTool binary file the `SCardListReaders` function returns: `SCardListReaders: Cannot find a smart card reader.`
I cannot Guess what the problem can be since I can see my USB reader when running `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 072f:8206 Advanced Card Systems, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

and I have run the PCSC daemon (`pcscd`) while running the code.

Can anyone help me solve this? Have I missed to install a specific driver or so?

Answer (score 1):

pcscd should log what is happening and if the reader driver is found.

See https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/#support to know how to generate a correct pcscd log.

Answer (score 0):

The fact, that your system identifies the USB reader as existing and connected is insufficent for knowing how to address it.

I assume, that the respective driver is missing (not sure, whether ACS provides one for Linux).

Comment: I have installed the official driver for this reader. still not working